# How to process SAML from idp initiated SSO using PHP?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml

I'm a service provider. The SSO process is being initiated at the idp, when someone clicks on a link, and the idp is posting SAML to my specified url endpoint. They've only provided me a metadata.xml file. Not sure this is all I need.

Using PHP, how do I process that SAML data, and how do I use the metadata.xml? do I need to install simplesamlphp or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simpleSAMLphp or just the "core" of that software that is able to handle SAML messages:
https://github.com/simplesamlphp/saml2

If you are looking for an easy approach, I recommend to take a look at another PHP SAML toolkit,  php-saml:
https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml